# Port number settings in cloud9, for elasticsearch and rails system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, cloud9-ide

now I'm working on a Full-text search system, using web browser UI to find any text data file in my local network.

Here is develop environment.

- OS：Macbook Air　El Capitan　10.11.6
- IDE:Cloud9
- Lang:Ruby on Rails
- SearchEngine:Elasticsearch

Using [this site](http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20151018/1445142266) as a reference, I faced problems of PORT number many times.

(don't need to read sentence, since it's written in Japanese)

==========

I got this error many times importing db:seed, making index( _elasticsearch__.
create.~), ... and so on.

> Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)

Also, I can't see anything in "localhost:9200" in my browser.
I had no setting about PORT number in cloud9, how should I do?

1. setting parameters in cloud9(cloud-network)
2. download this project from cloud9, and continue to make in local-network

which is better, or another better plan...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the elastic search documentation

> ## [Installation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch#installation)
>
> 1. [Download](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) and unzip the Elasticsearch official distribution.
> 2. Run bin/elasticsearch on unix, or bin\elasticsearch.bat on windows.
> 3. Run curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/.
> 4. Start more servers …

Comment: Thank you for your answering.
You mean no.2 choice, using terminal to make it? (not using Cloud9)